# Javascript - Storing array of objects in hidden field

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, post, serialization

I need to store some input in a hidden field, so when I print the post-request, I get:

```
Array ( [0]=>1 [1]=>2 [2]=>3 )
```

I already tried:

```
var elems = [];
elems.push['1'];
elems.push['2'];
elems.push['3'];

$('#input_hidden_field').val(elems);
```

But it does not work, anybody could help me with this?

Comment: Follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939840/javascript-hidden-input-array

Comment: You can only assign a string value to the `val` of an input field. What do you want to go in the field? Do you want the value formatted? `"1,2,3"`?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You can parse your array into a JSON-string to store it:

`.push()` is a function, therefore it needs `()` and not the `[]` array-syntax.

```
var elems = [];
elems.push('1');
elems.push('2');
elems.push('3');

$('#input_hidden_field').val(JSON.stringify(elems)); //store array

var value = $('#input_hidden_field').val(); //retrieve array
value = JSON.parse(value);
```

To create an object just change the definition of `elems` and the storage of the values:

```
var elems = {};
elems[0] = '1';
elems[1] = '2';
elems[2] = '3';
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/f4utg4e5/1/)

**Reference**

[.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

[.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: i need to create an object and than stringify it, could u help me with this?

Comment: Can we pass this json string to controller and retrieve our array back in controller ? 
if yes please help how to do that

Comment: @ZaidQureshi Yes, but this has nothing to do with the OP. So please feel free to submit a new question (or research on SO first, keyword AJAX)

Comment: Thank you. Found it very helpful.

Answer (score 9):

JS

```
var elems = [];
elems.push['1'];
elems.push['2'];
elems.push['3'];
$('#input_hidden_field').val(JSON.stringify(elems));
```

PHP

```
$elems = json_decode($_POST['hidden_input_name'], true);
```

Answer (score 5):

A better approach would be appending a new formdata for each value within an array.

JS

```
var elems = [];
elems.push['1'];
elems.push['2'];
elems.push['3']; 

var fd = new FormData(document.getElementById("myform"));
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
   fd.append('elems[]', elems[i]);
}
```

HTML

```
<form action="./post-request.php" method="post" id="myform">
   <input type="hidden" name="elems[]" />
   <button type="submit" name="myarray">SEND</button>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php 

   if(isset($_POST['myarray']) {
      print_r($_POST['elems']); 
   }
```

Comment: it depends on your needs, if this is "better"

Answer (score 0):

For a simple array of strings, just use the html name tag accordingly:

```
<input name="input_hidden_field[]"/>
```

This will just join the values in the input and give you back an array upon retrieval

```
$('name="input_hidden_field[]"']).val()
```