# How to move one ListBox text to another ListBox and get the value at server side?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, listbox

I have two listbox, I want to move items from to another listbox using jquery. This part is already done. Now I want to get those moved Item values in server side when i click the button.

Here is my code

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top:10px;">
   <div class="col-lg-3">
       <asp:ListBox ID="lstLeft" class="form-control" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Height="220px">
           <asp:ListItem Value="transactions.storeid as StoreID">StoreID</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Value="YEAR(transactions.Time) Year">Year</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Value="MONTH(transactions.Time) Month">Month</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Value="transactionsEntry.TransactionNumber">TransactionNumber</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Value="transactionsEntry.Quantity">Quantity</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Value="items.ItemLookupCode">ItemLookupCode</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Value="CONVERT(varchar, CAST(transactionsEntry.Price AS money), 1)*transactionsEntry.Quantity ExtendedPrice">ExtendedPrice</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Value="departments.Name as DepartmentName">DepartmentName</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Value="categories.Name as CategoryName">CategoryName</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Value="items.SubDescription1">SubDescription1</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Value="suppliers.SupplierName">SupplierName</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Value="suppliers.Code">Code</asp:ListItem>
       </asp:ListBox>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-1">
       <input type="button" id="left" value="<<" />
       <input type="button" id="right" value=">>" />
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-3">
       <asp:ListBox ID="lstRight" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Width="100%" Height="220"></asp:ListBox>
   </div>
</div>
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" class="btn btn-info" runat="server" Text="SEARCH" Width="100" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
```

jquery code:

```
$(function () {
            $("#left").bind("click", function () {
                var options = $("[id*=lstRight] option:selected");
                for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                    var opt = $(options[i]).clone();
                    $(options[i]).remove();
                    $("[id*=lstLeft]").append(opt);
                }
            });
            $("#right").bind("click", function () {
                var options = $("[id*=lstLeft] option:selected");
                for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                    var opt = $(options[i]).clone();
                    $(options[i]).remove();
                    $("[id*=lstRight]").append(opt);
                }
            });
        });
```

Upto this it's working fine. Now I want to get the text and values which is move to 1stRight listbox on server side.

Thanks

Comment: You have to maintain both left and right list in javascript object and after finishing left right operation store that lists in to hidden fields using json. You can access both json strings at server side using those hidden fields.

Comment: @MD's Can you give some links to refer the code?. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29076219/javascript-storing-array-of-objects-in-hidden-field

Answer (score 0):

Html code:

```
 <div class="row" style="padding-top: 10px;">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <asp:ListBox ID="lstLeft" class="form-control" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Height="220px">
                <asp:ListItem Value="transactions.storeid as StoreID">StoreID</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="YEAR(transactions.Time) Year">Year</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="MONTH(transactions.Time) Month">Month</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="transactionsEntry.TransactionNumber">TransactionNumber</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="transactionsEntry.Quantity">Quantity</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="items.ItemLookupCode">ItemLookupCode</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="CONVERT(varchar, CAST(transactionsEntry.Price AS money), 1)*transactionsEntry.Quantity ExtendedPrice">ExtendedPrice</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="departments.Name as DepartmentName">DepartmentName</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="categories.Name as CategoryName">CategoryName</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="items.SubDescription1">SubDescription1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="suppliers.SupplierName">SupplierName</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="suppliers.Code">Code</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:ListBox>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1">

            <asp:Button ID="btnLeft" runat="server" Text="&lt;&lt; Server" OnClick="btnLeft_Click" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnRight" runat="server" Text="&gt;&gt; Server" OnClick="btnRight_Click"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <asp:ListBox ID="lstRight" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Width="100%" Height="220"></asp:ListBox>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Code Behind code :

```
    protected void btnLeft_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Move(lstRight, lstLeft);
    }
    protected void btnRight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Move(lstLeft, lstRight);
    }
    private void Move(ListBox from, ListBox to)
    {
        var selected = from.Items.OfType<ListItem>().Where(x => x.Selected);
        var listItems = selected as ListItem[] ?? selected.ToArray();

        foreach (ListItem item in listItems)
        {
            to.Items.Add(new ListItem(item.Text, item.Value));
        }
        from.ClearSelection();

        foreach (var item in listItems)
        {
            from.Items.Remove(new ListItem(item.Text, item.Value));
        }

    }
```

Comment: Oh my God!. This will reload the page each and every time. I don't want this.

Answer (score 0):

or Alternative way :

```
        <div class="row" style="padding-top: 10px;">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <asp:ListBox ID="lstLeft" class="form-control" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Height="220px">
                <asp:ListItem Value="transactions.storeid as StoreID">StoreID</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="YEAR(transactions.Time) Year">Year</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="MONTH(transactions.Time) Month">Month</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="transactionsEntry.TransactionNumber">TransactionNumber</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="transactionsEntry.Quantity">Quantity</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="items.ItemLookupCode">ItemLookupCode</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="CONVERT(varchar, CAST(transactionsEntry.Price AS money), 1)*transactionsEntry.Quantity ExtendedPrice">ExtendedPrice</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="departments.Name as DepartmentName">DepartmentName</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="categories.Name as CategoryName">CategoryName</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="items.SubDescription1">SubDescription1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="suppliers.SupplierName">SupplierName</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="suppliers.Code">Code</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:ListBox>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1">
            <input type="button" id="toLeft" value="<<" />
            <input type="button" id="toRight" value=">>" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <asp:ListBox ID="lstRight" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Width="100%" Height="220"></asp:ListBox>
        </div>
    </div>
```

javascript code:

```
     function SendForm(controlName) {
        var from;
        var to;
        var list = [];
        if (controlName == 'toLeft') {
            from = $("[id*=lstRight] option:selected");
            to = $("[id*=lstLeft]");
        } else {
            from = $("[id*=lstLeft] option:selected");
            to = $("[id*=lstRight]");
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < from.length; i++) {
            var opt = $(from[i]).clone();
            list.push(opt[0].innerHTML);
            $(from[i]).remove();
            to.append(opt);
        }
        PageMethods.SendForm(list, controlName, OnSucceeded, OnFailed);
    }

    function OnSucceeded() {
        //..
    }

    function OnFailed(error) {
        // Alert user to the error.
        alert(error.get_message());
    }


    $(function () {
        $("#toLeft").bind("click", function () {
            SendForm('toLeft');
        });
        $("#toRight").bind("click", function () {
            SendForm('toRight');
        });
    });
```

Code Behind :

```
  [WebMethod]
  public static void SendForm(string[] optionValues, string controlName)
  {
      // something ..
  }
```