# How to pass an array created in javascript to another jsp and then use that array in a java function on that jsp?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

Here is a script i have and I want to be able to pass the array "playernames" into a java function on another .jsp. I'm wonder how to pass that array to another page and then retrieve it for my java function.

```
<script>
function getPlayerNames() {
      var selected = document.querySelectorAll("#selected-players > tr > td");
      var playernames = [];
      for(var i=0; i<selected.length; ++i){
         var id = selected[i].getAttribute('id');
         if (id.indexOf('Player')>-1) {
             playernames.push(selected[i].textContent);
         }

      }  
}
</script>
```

Edit:

```
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><button   onclick="getPlayerNames()"id="generate">Generate</button><br></td>

<input type="hidden" id="players" />

<script>
function getPlayerNames(){
      var selected = document.querySelectorAll("#selected-players > tr >    td");
      var playernames = [];
      for(var i=0; i<selected.length; ++i){
         var id = selected[i].getAttribute('id');
         if (id.indexOf('Player')>-1) {
             playernames.push(selected[i].textContent);
         }

      }
      document.getElementById("players").values=playernames;
      document.getElementById("players").submit();
      window.location.replace("lineups.jsp");   
}</script>
```

Other jsp

```
<%String[] players = request.getParameterValues("players");%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to have the hidden field inside the form tags with the id and action attributes set as below.

```
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><button   onclick="getPlayerNames()"id="generate">Generate</button><br></td>

<form id="playerNames" action="Url"> // In action give the Url of the jsp page you want to send the values to lineups.jsp in your case I guess.
<input type="hidden" id="players" name="players" />
</form>

<script>
function getPlayerNames(){
      var selected = document.querySelectorAll("#selected-players > tr >    td");
      var playernames = [];
      for(var i=0; i<selected.length; ++i){
         var id = selected[i].getAttribute('id');
         if (id.indexOf('Player')>-1) {
             playernames.push(selected[i].textContent);
         }

      }

         document.getElementById("players").value=playernames;
      document.getElementById("playerNames").submit();
}</script>
```

Comment: I have the array assigned to a hidden form. How do i send that hidden form to the other jsp if lets say I have a button that is sending me to the other jsp?

Comment: For a better demonstration of how and when to submit the form you'll need to post the code for your form as well as how you are setting the hidden form field value.

Comment: You are welcome! But are you forgetting something?? maybe mark this post as an answer! :)

Comment: New here. Not seeing how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

1) Stringify the array and then assign to hidden field.
Refer: [Javascript Hidden Input Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939840/javascript-hidden-input-array)
2) Submit the hidden field in a form to server.

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenArrayField"/>
document.getElementById("hiddenArrayField").value=yourStringifyArrayValue;
```

3) On server you would get this as a part of request i.e. on next jsp you can retrieve this value as a request parameter.

```
  <%= request.getParameter("hiddenArrayField")%>
```

Comment: Could you edit my answer in that case, what more steps are needed?

Comment: Isn't the first bit of code demonstrating part 1? what would be the code for submitting the hidden field in a form to the server?